# Php and sql query

Tags: php, sql-server, database, odbc

i wanted to know if they could help me because I have a problem with sql and php query, I need to add the number of units sold each vendor, I am limiting the number of records to show only as evidence, because the database contains hundreds of records.
I get this error:

> Warning: odbc_exec (): SQL error: [TOD] [ODBC] [GENESIS] Non aggregates require a GROUP BY expression.
>
> Warning: odbc_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

I searched a lot on internet but in trying to group them with the function group by, still gives me the same error.
I leave part of my code, I hope you can help and thanks in advance!

```
 <?php 
  $sqlVend = "select top 10 VEN_LLAVE, VEN_NOMBRE, VDOC_UDS,
                     sum(VDOC_UDS) as suma 
              from VENVEN, VENDOC 
              where VENVEN.VEN_LLAVE = VENDOC.VDOC_VEND group by VEN_LLAVE";
  $resVend = odbc_exec($cone, $sqlVend);
  while (odbc_fetch_row($resVend)) {
    # code...
?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo odbc_result($resVend, 'VEN_LLAVE') ?></td>
  <td><?php echo odbc_result($resVend, 'VEN_NOMBRE') ?></td>
  <td><?php echo odbc_result($resVend, 'suma') ?></td>

</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Correct DBMS tags on your question may yield faster results.

Comment: I don't see where you tried to use GROUP BY.

Comment: I have changed, thanks for your help

Comment: If this is in fact for SQL-Server, you will need all columns that aren't aggregated to be in the `GROUP BY` clause. e.g. `GROUP BY VEN_LLAVE, VEN_NOMBRE`

Comment: @bjones, First of all thank you very much for your answer.
I modified the query with your answer, apparently if it worked only this taking too long to show, in fact even it shows because many records, is supposed to only calculate the units of the top 10 sellers. Can you help me again please?
Thanks for your help friend.

Comment: @Byte, I corrected the `GROUP BY`. You don't need `VDOC_UDS` because it is being aggregated. Maybe that will speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

Again, I modified the `GROUP BY` clause to only include `VEN_LLAVE, VEN_NOMBRE`. You don't need `VDOC_UDS` because it is being aggregated with `SUM()`.

```
SELECT TOP 10 VEN_LLAVE, VEN_NOMBRE,
              SUM(VDOC_UDS) as Suma 
FROM VENVEN, VENDOC 
WHERE VENVEN.VEN_LLAVE = VENDOC.VDOC_VEND 
GROUP BY VEN_LLAVE, VEN_NOMBRE
```

Comment: ,Thanks again buddy.
But when I deleted VDOC_UDS again showed errors raised.
I put the code as it is what you suggest and it did not work. Do you need more info? or what I can do?

Comment: @bjones - You mention in your post but never take `VDOC_UDS` out of `SELECT` clause.

Comment: @Byte check updated answer. Although I'm not sure that will fix both errors.